# C# Simulating keyboard press on OS below Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-7, sendkeys

I am using the following code in C# to simulate the keyboard pressing:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

void sim_key(string text, string proc)
{
    var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(proc).FirstOrDefault();
    if (process != null && process.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
        SendKeys.Send(kat_id);
    }
}
```

I tested it on Windows Xp, 7, 8.1, 10, and Server 2012. On windows 7 and Xp, the external app window is handled properly, however the keys are not being sent. On systems above Win 7 everything is correct. How should I fix it?

Edit:
I checked it on .NET 4.0 Client Profile and .NET 4.6.1 on 32 and 64 bit machines, but results are the same as described above.

Comment: You could try keybd_event instead of SendKeys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can go with this rough code

```
    const int WM_CHAR = 0x0102;
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

if (process != null && process.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
      PostMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, WM_CHAR, (int) <a character you want to send> , 1);
    }
```

Use

```
PostMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, 13, 1);
```

to send the "Enter".

Note that you can use `SendMessage` instead of `PostMessage`. The difference is the last one does not wait the processing of the key. They have the same signature:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
```

You don't need calling `SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);` if you just want to send keys.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I tried using PostMessage to send Ctrl+F10 to the other window. Here is my code:

```
public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
public const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
public const int VK_CONTROL = 0x11;
public const int VK_F10 = 0x79;

PostMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, null);
PostMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F10, null);
PostMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, VK_F10, null);
PostMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, VK_CONTROL, null);
```

However, it doesn't pass the keys to the app.